# Android Create Bitmap from RelativeLayout ChildView not scalling properly

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout

Here is the code for convert view to bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

}

Above code create real size bitmap properly. But all child position is not scaling with layout ratio.

Comment: do you need screenshot of that view?

Comment: Not at all. Screenshot using Drawing Cache reduce the view actual resolution. Need to grab the entire view of layout including child @Jayanth